# REST principles - returning a simple response

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django REST framework. By default, all the requests returns a JSON object containing the pagination (`prev`, `next`, `count`, `results`). This is useful in 90% of the cases where the user retrieves or creates info about something. However, there are a few resources which don't have to return anything but rather a confirmation that everything went smoothly - for example, imagine a resource which is just a `heartbeat` request ("ping") to maintain the session active.

Would it be okay to return a simple response, such as `{result: true}` (without any pagination like the rest of resources have) or would this be an eventual violation of the REST principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ouf course such a response to a ping request is OK. Pagination is something only suitable for a collection that can be paged. Paging An unique resource that is not a collection does not make sense.

For the ping request you could even leave the response body empty.

Request:

```
GET /ping
```

Response:

```
200 OK
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Would the response not need to be pong?

Comment: @WillS Of courese. But since OP the wrote: "there are a few resources which don't have to return anything but rather a confirmation that everything went smoothly", I skipped the `pong` response body :)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to know if the URI is fully serviceable, disregarding the body completely, you should simply support a `HEAD` request instead of `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination should be solved with range headers or hyperlinks. You don't need the body in empty responses, just the status header.